# Can't get Java to allow an applet to run

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to test a java applet that I'm working on, which is running on my VM. When I try to run it from any of my browsers in windows, I get the message "The Java security settings have prevented this application from running".

In the Java control panel, I've added the domain and the specific page to the list of site exceptions. I've imported the self-signed certificate and added it to the list of Trusted Authorities. I've also set the security level to Medium.

In the applet's manifest.mf file, I've got the codebase set to "*" (I initially had it set more specifically but made it lenient just to make sure that wasn't the issue).

I'm not sure what else to try in order to get this applet to run

Comment: This might help --> https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my manifest.mf file. I had changed the Codebase but not the Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase. Setting:

"Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *"

fixed my problem.